# Regex to match against something that is not a specific substring

Tags: c#, java, regex, regex-negation

I am looking for a regex that will match a string that starts with one substring and does not end with a certain substring.

Example:

```
// Updated to be correct, thanks @Apocalisp
^foo.*(?<!bar)$
```

Should match anything that starts with "foo" and doesn't end with "bar".  I know about the [^...] syntax, but I can't find anything that will do that for a string instead of single characters.

I am specifically trying to do this for Java's regex, but I've run into this before so answers for other regex engines would be great too.

Thanks to @Kibbee for verifying that this works in C# as well.

Comment: As I mentioned below - regexp in question for input string "foo123bar" it will match "foo12" - hope this is desired behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think in this case you want **negative lookbehind**, like so:

```
foo.*(?<!bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java regex but documentation for the [Pattern Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) would suggest you could use (?!X) for a non-capturing zero-width negative lookahead (it looks for something that is not X at that postision, without capturing it as a backreference). So you could do:

```
foo.*(?!bar) // not correct
```

**Update**: Apocalisp's right, you want negative lookbehind. (you're checking that what the .* matches doesn't end with bar)

Comment: Problem with this solution is in the fact that for input string "foo123bar" it will match "foo12" - hope this is desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Verified @Apocalisp's answer using:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^foo.*(?<!bar)$");
    System.out.println(p.matcher("foobar").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("fooBLAHbar").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("1foo").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("fooBLAH-ar").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("foo").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("foobaz").matches());
  }
}
```

This output the the right answers:

```
false
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters said, you need a negative lookahead. In Java you can use this pattern:

```
"^first_string(?!.?second_string)\\z"
```

- ^ - ensures that string starts with
  first_string
- \z - ensures that string ends with second_string
- (?!.?second_string) - means that first_string can't be followed by second_string