# Java regex @ strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help using regex in java.

Im trying to achieve 2 different validations and i dont really know how (all i know is that there's a matches method you might use):

1) Making sure a string **DOESNT** include one of very specific characters lets say (char1, char2..)

And (in seperated validation - not same regex pattern as 1):

2) Making sure a string **DOES** include a pattern of "anythingCanBeHere@anythingCanBeHere" note that "" (empty string) and "anythingCanBeHere@" is valid BUT "@anythingCanBeHere" isn't valid. btw, can i somehow use this regex to split in a correct way of the first value before @ and second value which is after @?

Much thanks guys, waiting for ur answer :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good link for regex is at http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Try checking out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198781/regex-to-tell-if-a-string-does-not-contain-a-specific-character] at least for the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate your input like this:

```
boolean checkInput1( String input )
{
    return input.matches( "^[^bla]*$" );
}

boolean checkInput2( String input )
{
    if ( input.length() == 0 ) return true;
    return input.matches( "^[^@]+@.*$" );
}
```

Replace `bla` here with the specific characters you don't want to be included.

Comment: first, thank you for your answer! 1. why did u use pattern and matcher objects instead of doing something like String.matches("pattern..") ? 2. how does it guarantee that must be a sequence before @ ?

Comment: String.matches is indeed a better option, corrected that now. The regular expression guarantees that there must be a sequence before @ with the + modifier. The + modifier requires that there are one or more occurrences.

Comment: okay I now get it but there's still a problem since i dont want to limit the pattern with a certain string of 'bla' when i wrote 'anything can be here' i ment that any string is optional (this is dynamic).. should i remove the bla and that's it?

Comment: No, you don't understand what the role of 'bla' is here. The characters after the ^ sign are the characters that cannot be in the string. In this case there is no valid match if the string contains 'b', 'l' or 'a'. You just need to replace that with the characters you don't want.

Comment: oh i see, the thing is that i didn't want to include both (1) and (2) in same regex, i wanted to separate them meaning i need two different validations sorry if i didn't explain it right..

Comment: :) Thanks a lot. Hope im not bugging with questions but id like to enrich my knowledge for future - how would the regex look like if i did allow "@anythingCanBeHere" ?