# In the TortoiseSVN log, what regexp can I use to search for entries *not* by a particular author?

Tags: regex, tortoisesvn

I'm looking at the log messages for a particular branch in TortoiseSVN.  We have an automated build process which has commits regularly to the branch using the author "builder".

In the TortoiseSVN search box, you can filter by authors and you can use regular expressions... what search expression can I use to show all the log messages not committed by author "builder"?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add !(builder) to the filter box

kindness,

dan

Answer (score 6):

As agileguy already mentioned, the string "!(builder)" will work.

But as for an explanation:

- the '!' if it's the first char of the filter string will negate the filter
- the '()' would have the regex put the search/filter string 'builder' into a regex group. Since that's not really necessary, you could also just use "!builder" instead of "!(builder)" as the filter string.

Comment: Good point, well made :) A little explanation would not have gone amiss!