# Parsing table like strings

Tags: php, regex

I have a complex string that represents database tables. And I need to extract that database tables separately to process them.

Here's the string example:

```
First table
    | | {{Категория}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}} | {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
    | 1 | Взрослый | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~500 лей | 15 евро |
    | 2 |   Студент, Мастерант, Докторант | 1 уровень = 50ч | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 3 | Ученик | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 4 | Пенсионер | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
text text  text text text text
    Second table:
        | | {{Вид курсов}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}}| {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
        | 1 | dfgdfgdfg | 1 модуль | 500 лей |  0 |
        |^|^| 2 модуля | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| 4 модуля | 1~500 лей | 0 |
        | 2 | fgdfgdfg | 12ч | 800 лей | 0 |
        | 3 | dfgdfgdfgdfg| 12ч | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| Предварительный тест | 400 лей | 0 |
text text text text text text
```

I tried using this regexp: `\|.+` but `preg_match_all()` simply dumps all the tables unseparated in the array. Any help, please? Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just using an existing/sane format like, say, JSON?

Comment: `\|.+` matches a pipe (`|`) and then any number of any characters (`.+`). Try `/\|[^|]+/` instead

Comment: @MattBall because this format is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see, you have a set of tables within one string. And you need to split string to tables. I assume you could split the string with the text, separating tables.

```
<?php
$s = <<<EOSTR
First table
    | | {{Категория}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}} | {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
    | 1 | Взрослый | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~500 лей | 15 евро |
    | 2 |   Студент, Мастерант, Докторант | 1 уровень = 50ч | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 3 | Ученик | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 4 | Пенсионер | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
text text  text text text text
    Second table:
        | | {{Вид курсов}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}}| {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
        | 1 | dfgdfgdfg | 1 модуль | 500 лей |  0 |
        |^|^| 2 модуля | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| 4 модуля | 1~500 лей | 0 |
        | 2 | fgdfgdfg | 12ч | 800 лей | 0 |
        | 3 | dfgdfgdfgdfg| 12ч | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| Предварительный тест | 400 лей | 0 |
text text text text text text
EOSTR;

$a = null;
$a = preg_split('/^(?:.(?<!\|))*$/xm', $s);
var_dump($a);
```

Just like here: http://ideone.com/VCt4f (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876927/regex-for-matching-lines-that-do-not-contain-a-word)). This will give you this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(506) "
    | | {{Категория}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}} | {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
    | 1 | Взрослый | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~500 лей | 15 евро |
    | 2 |   Студент, Мастерант, Докторант | 1 уровень = 50ч | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 3 | Ученик | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
    | 4 | Пенсионер | 1 уровень = 50ч  | 1~000 лей | 15 евро |
"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "
"
  [3]=>
  string(466) "
        | | {{Вид курсов}} | | {{Стоимость курсов}}| {{Стоимость учебного набора}} |
        | 1 | dfgdfgdfg | 1 модуль | 500 лей |  0 |
        |^|^| 2 модуля | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| 4 модуля | 1~500 лей | 0 |
        | 2 | fgdfgdfg | 12ч | 800 лей | 0 |
        | 3 | dfgdfgdfgdfg| 12ч | 900 лей | 0 |
        |^|^| Предварительный тест | 400 лей | 0 |
"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

When you're done extracting tables you could simply split them to columns with

```
// $a = preg_split...

foreach ($a as $table) {
    if (!strlen(trim($table)))
         continue;

    $rows = preg_split('/\n/', $table);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if (!strlen(trim($row)))
            continue;

        $columns = preg_split('/\|/', $row);

        // work with $columns array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) function on "|" and " " (space) and parse it that way. Other then that, I cant really think of any other way.

```
$exploded = explode("|", $table);
$exploded = explode(" ", $table);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler and faster just to exchange the regexp with two explodes and an iteration

```
$table = array();
$rows = explode("\n", $string);

foreach($rows as $row)
    $table[] = explode("|", $row);
```

Now we have a 2d array structure so that we easily can echo out as a table, like this

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($table as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($row as $column)
        echo "<td>$column</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it's not what i need. You see there is a lot of text there that can have "\n" symbols so whe making the first explode it explodes that content too. but thx anyway