# Regex for matching lines that does not contain specifc lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to get only the line that is an extra parameter from a set of data. E.g.

```
 abc#def
 String A
 Stringfoo B
 foo C
 Line D
 Linefoo E
 extra parameter
```

My desired output would be

```
extra parameter
```

However, it can be in any order E.g.

```
 abc#def
 String A
 Stringfoo B
 foo C
 extra parameter 
 Line D
 Linefoo E
```

how would i go about this?
i saw the solution from [Regex for matching lines that do NOT contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876927/regex-for-matching-lines-that-do-not-contain-a-word) but it did not work.

Also, I tried to do a negetive lookaround e.g.

```
^((?!Line 5).)*$
```

to see i am able to get the rest but sadly, am not sure what am i doing wrong. Please advise! Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify what the desired goal is? Is `Line 5` actual text or a blank line. Are you trying to grab anything that has two words separated by a space that does not match the pattern of `Line\s\d+`? Do you just want the last line? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Ah my apologise, i forgot to add that that the "asdsasfasfasdf asdasdasd" might be in any line other than the first line

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "extra parameter from a set of data"? How exactly is it different?

Comment: If you just want the last line see @Yukulélé's answer below

Comment: my set of data that i receive is as follows:
`abc#def
 Line 1
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
 Line 5`
but sometimes it might give me also an extra parameter like:
` abc#def
 Line 1
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
extra parameter
 Line 5`
so i would need to know what is the extra parameter that is given to me

Comment: Is your input always going to have the exact text "Line 1" or are you using Line 1 as a placeholder for any text? Your example is very confusing

Comment: It is a place holder, sorry for the confusion.
however the format is the same with a space in between strings

Comment: What does "Line 1"  represent and how is it different from extra parameter? Will each line have some word, a space, and a number except for one of them? `Dog 1 Cat 2 chicken chicken`? Where `chicken chicken` would be extra parameter

Comment: yes `chicken chicken` would be the extra parameter, but it might be in any order. Also, all would be a string of text

Comment: So is it correct to say you want to find any line that is not some word, a space, and a number? What is the pattern we are trying to find or avoid?

Comment: You might want to edit the title of your post. Your question makes it sound like you are looking for Yukulélé's answer, but I don't think you are

Comment: is this what you are looking for? - https://regex101.com/r/GLVOo6/2

Comment: How is "Line D" different from "extra parameter" will Line D only ever have one character in the second word?

Comment: No, it might have more character in the second word

Comment: How can we distinguish between "Line D" and "extra parameter" they both appear to be two words separated by a space. It's like you are saying pick out the only one that is a fruit from a basket that has an apple, an orange, and a banana. They are all fruit so I can't pick. You need to tell me something unique about "extra parameter" or how it is different from the other lines in your input.

Comment: Yes, they are separated by a space. My initial plan was to use a regex something like this `^(?!.*(String|Stringfoo|foo|Line|Linefoo)).*$` to get `extra parameter`

Comment: It can be in anyline after the first line

Answer (score 0):

Did you try regexOptions.Multiline, if you are working with .net flavor.?
This option will search for match in every line.
By using tempered token (?!Line) you are eliminating the lines which have Line in it.

^((?!Line).)*$

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%28%3f!Line%29.%29*%24&i=+abc%23def%0d%0a+Line+1%0d%0a+Line+2%0d%0a+Line+3%0d%0a+Line+4%0d%0a+Line+5%0d%0a+asdsasfasfasdf+asdasdasd&o=sm

Upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the last line, aren't you ?

try this:

```js
/[^\n]*$/
```

"zero or more non new line chars followed by end of string"

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at what you are looking for

`^\w+\s[^\d]+$`

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GLVOo6/1)

Any line that starts with a word separated by a space not followed by a number