# Negating a set of words via java regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I would like to negate a set of words using java regex.

Say, I want to negate `cvs`, `svn`, `nvs`, `mvc`. I wrote a regex which is `^[(svn|cvs|nvs|mvc)]`.

Some how that seems not to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990/regex-to-match-against-something-that-is-not-a-specific-substring

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string

Comment: This kind of question appears quite often so I think it deserves a tag.  I've added one called "regex-negation".

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?!.*(svn|cvs|nvs|mvc)).*$
```

this will match text if it doesn't contain one of svn, cvs, nvs or mvc.

This is a similar question: [C# Regex to match a string that doesn't contain a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318279/c-regex-to-match-a-string-that-doesnt-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong. Between square brackets, you can put characters to require or to ignore. If you don't find `^(svn|cvs|nvs|mvc)$`, you're fine.

Comment: that actually not helpful as this is not purely regex. if you don't have to option to change code, this won't solve the QAs issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. If you want to negate a word you have to split it to letters and negate each letter.

so to negate

```
/svn/
```

you have to write

```
/[^s][^v][^n]/
```

So what you want to filter out will turn into really ugly regex and I think it's better idea to use this regex

```
/svn|cvs|nvs|mvc/
```

and when you test your string against it, just negate the result.

In JS this would look more less like that:

```
!/svn|cvs|nvs|mvc/.test("this is your test string");
```

Comment: that's probably not correct, because you don't match the beginning ^ and the end $ of the string

Comment: Well, I'm searching for any of the words on any position in a test string. If you want to match only the whole words then ^ at the beginning and $ at the end will do the trick.