# How to say this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I want a java regular expression, that can be used to match this text:

`variable(X)`.

The `X` can be any string, that only contains characters `a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`.

But the rules are, `X != tab` and `X != foo`.

Also the `X` cannot be empty string.

Also `X` must begin with a `a-z` character.

So far I have `variable\([a-z]([a-zA-Z]|\d)*\)`,  but I don't know how to write the not equals to part...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333540/negating-a-set-of-words-via-java-regex

Comment: See: [Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
^variable\s*\(((?!(?:foo|tab)\))[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\)
```

In Java:

```
^variable\\s*\\(((?!(?:foo|tab)\\))[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/0TN8bmmQLS

Comment: I changed it to, tab and foo.
also, this allows the first character to be capital, which it shouldn't.

Comment: How are you restricting the characters to be a-z,A-Z,0-9 ?

Comment: @omega: check the edited answer and new link on rubular. This regex only allows `a-zA-Z0-9` starting from `a-z`

Comment: the new one, doesn't match `variable(fooo)`, but it should.

Comment: Sorry check new edit now.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.