# Mule File matcher excluding a pattern

Tags: mule, glob, mule4

I am trying to write a GLOB pattern to exclude a partially downloaded file to be read by the File Listener. I am using the file name pattern foo.*[^filepart] in the File matcher but it doesn't works.

Please suggest.

```
<file:matcher name="filename-regex-filter" doc:name="Matcher" doc:id="410af88e-b6c6-4816-aaff-1f4edc29214f" filenamePattern="foo.*[^filepart]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

filenamePattern is a regular expression. In regular expressions the pattern `[^abc]` excludes any of the set of characters after `^`.

For example `abc[^def]` matches `abcd`, `abce` and `abcf`, but it doesn't match `abcdef`.

The answer is in previous questions about how to exclude words in regular expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333787/721855 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078953/721855. Use the `(?!X)` expression instead.

Example: `foo.*(?!filepart)`

Comment: Thanks. I found out the we can use regex instead of GLOB, we just have to append "regex:" at the beginning of the expression.